# How to count statements in C ignoring the comments

Tags: count

```
int Emptylines(FILE *fp);
int Numberofstatements(FILE *fp);

int main() {
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  FILE *fp1 = NULL;
  int n1, n2;
  char fname[255], fname1[255];
  printf("Enter file name for reading");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%s", &fname);
  fp = fopen(fname, "r");

  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("File with name %s couldn't be open", fname);
    exit(1);
  }

  n1 = Emptylines(fp); // this is for empty lines
  n2 = Numberofstatements(fp);
  printf("Insert file name for writing");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%s", &fname1);
  fp1 = fopen(fname1, "w+");
  fprintf(fp1, "The number of empty lines=%d", n1);
  fprintf(fp1, "The number of statements=%d", n2);
  fclose(fp);
  fclose(fp1);
  return 0;
}

int Numberofstatements(FILE *fp) {
  char line[128];
  int nofstatements = 0;

  while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
    if (strstr(line, "if") != 0)
      nofstatements++; 
  }
  return nofstatements;
}
```

I need to count all statements like `if`, `do`, `while`, `break`, etc. as well as empty lines and then save the result in a new file. I succeed in counting the empty lines but I have no idea how to count the statements. I tried 2 different ways but both failed.

I also need to ignore comments while reading the code, so if there is a `for`, `while`, etc. in the comments it shouldn't be counted.

Comment: If you want to do this right, you'll have to implement a proper C parser to handle situations like `char* pStr = "while ( ... ) {...};";` and the like.

Comment: Technically speaking, doing `fflush(stdin)` is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), some C libraries allows it as an extension, but it's not "proper" C.

Comment: Get whole line using `fgets` and use `strstr` function

Comment: You'll also have to ignore anything `"in quotes"`, while also taking care of *escaped* quotes within the text.

Comment: Tnx for the help guys, i'll see what i can do

Comment: ok guys i edit it but it wont work again the result is always 0. I just tried with if so i can see if it works, i want to be able to do this then ill think of ignoring the comments and quotes

Answer (score 0):

A very basic answer addressing the fundamental issue (although there are others).

When you call `int Numberofstatements(FILE *fp)` you already reached the end of file in `int Emptylines(FILE *fp);` so you must add the statement

```
rewind(fp);
```

before trying to parse the file for a second time. Good luck with developing this.

Answer (score 0):

OP asks: "Any ideas ?"

To do properly, suggest reading 1 `char` at a time.  Keep track if you are in 1) on an include line, 2) inside a " " 3) inside a ' ' 4) in a // comment 5) inside a /* comment or 6) just plain code (watch for escape sequences).  When in plain code look for the keywords do, while, etc. and all the while count the `'\n'`.

To do correctly - this is not an easy task - about 10x the code you have posted.

Sample beginning of a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

```
state = plaincode;
while ((c = getc()) != EOF) {
  switch (state) {
    slashslash_commnet:
      if (c == '\n) state = plaincode;
      break;
    plaincode:
      if (c == '/') {
        c2 = getc();
        if (c2 == '/') { state =  slashslash_commnet; break; }
        else if (c2 == '*') { state =  slashstar_commnet:  break; }
        else unget(c2);
      else if (c == '\"') {
        ...
```